# How to add filter product search result by product attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter

i want add a filter in search result page, filter by attribute. How to make it? Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to

> Store -> Attributes -> Product

Edit your required attribute in **"Storefront Properties"** tab select **"Use in Search Results Layered Navigation"** value to **"Yes"**

and do a reindex

after this filters would appear. But it will not appear if only one filter available.

Example: Let's say you have a brand attribute which should appear on search filters and you have searched for **'Nike'** and all products appear for **Nike** then brand attribute would not appear because it has just one filter **"Nike"**. Whereas if you search for **"Black"** then it will show you all products with the text **Black** then multiple brands will appear on filters.

Hope you find your solution.